# How to combine first name, middle name and last name, where middlename is either empty or null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to concat firstname, lastname and middlename using SQL Server.

SQL I am trying to use is:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ',FirstName,MiddleName,LastName),'  ',' ') AS Name
FROM dbo.address
```

But this query is giving me a weird output in some cases:

Here are the sample data in my use case.

| firstname | middlename | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | NULL | Lapp |
| John |  | Lapp |
| John |  | Lapp |
| Accounts | NULL | Payable |
| Accounts |  | Payable |
| Accounts |  | Payable |
| Accounts | NULL | Payable |

But in the output, there is one additional space in the `name` when the middlename is empty. Sorry for the screenshot for the output.

[image]

But in another case with the same type of data, where middlename is null or empty, it gives the correct output, which means there is no additional space in between the name when the middle name is an empty string.

[image]

After trying the answer to the question, I got another weird result.

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 4):

The `CONCAT_WS` function is working its magic.  The problem is that you either have empty string or single space for some of the middle name values, in certain records.  Rightfully, the missing middle names should always be `NULL`.  Here is one workaround:

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstName,
                   CASE WHEN MiddleName NOT IN ('', ' ') THEN MiddleName END,
                   LastName) AS Name
FROM dbo.address;
```

The logic here is to replace an empty string or single space middle name with `NULL`, thereby allowing `CONCAT_WS` to ignore it.

Comment: I would suggest adding an ISNULL in the case statement to handle NULL values also

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh No need.  `CONCAT_WS` is already null safe, and will ignore `NULL` values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried your answer and got again a different output in null cases. which I have added as the screenshot in the question.

Comment: Then maybe the first name has trailing whitespace or the last name leading whitespace.  It seems my answer is working for some of the null middle names, but not all.  I would be suspecting the data at this point.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  it looks alright with eyes, but I am confused on how to check it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
select FName+' '+ IsNull(NullIf(MName + ' ',''),'') + LName
from tblName
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get started I would use trim function to sanitize the inputs and remove all the possible trailing and leading spaces

```
select concat_ws(' ', trim(firstname), isnull(trim(middlename), ''), trim(lastname)),
  from src_data;
```

But trim(' ') returns an empty symbol which is not null and from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

"CONCAT_WS ignores null values during concatenation, and does not add the separator between null values."

It means concat_ws will return

| source record | result |
| --- | --- |
| "John - null - Doe" | "John - space - Doe" |
| "John - empty symbol - Doe | "John - space+space - Doe" |

So, all is left is to convert all the empty symbols to nulls

```
select concat_ws(' ', trim(firstname), replace(trim(middlename), '', null), trim(lastname))
  from src_data;
```

I did that for the middle name but, since user input has definitely not been sanitized properly, I'd do that for first- and lastname too

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1cc4a8a2720df414f0cd3edbece15491)